# Rust: Static on trait with type params?

Tags: generics, rust, static-methods

I'm new to Rust, so bear with me.

I'm trying to create an static method for a trait which has type params.

```rust
trait MyTrait<R>{}

impl MyTrait{
   fn exactly(to: &str)-> dyn MyTrait<&str> {...}
}
```

Not possible given `MyTrait` requires a type param, so the compiler complains.

So if that's not the way, what's the way?

Comment: Does the compiler complain about missing `<...>` on `impl MyTrait`? If so please include the error message. However, you should also address your typos (like `fun`-> `fn`) and be aware that `MyTrait<&str>` is not a *type* and can't be used as a return type.

Comment: You mean I have to add the "dyn" or "impl" keyword?

Comment: That's just not how traits work. You can't just implement a trait, you have to implement it *for* some type. If you want a static method common for all implementations, you can include a default implementation in the trait definition itself.

Comment: You also can't have an `impl Trait` block. It has to be `impl Trait for Type`, or move the function to the `trait Trait` block.

Comment: Well, it was possible in previous editions - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=23aac490aa860cfe36d7ce54d9ab8802 - but it was equivalent to `impl dyn Trait`, and in the 2021 edition the latter is enforced.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is how static trait functions work in Rust 2021:

```rust
trait Trait<R> {}

impl dyn Trait<&str> {
    fn foo(to: &str) {}
}
```

However, your desired return value is simply impossible.

A trait is an **abstraction** of a real object. It can't exist on its own, there **must** be a real object **somewhere**. So a function that returns `dyn MyTrait<&str>` must store its value somewhere. `dyn` objects cannot exist on their own, they must be either behind a `&` reference or a `Box`.

However, if configured correctly, it **can** work for `impl` return values:

```rust
struct MyStruct<'a>(&'a str);
impl MyTrait<&str> for MyStruct<'_> {}

trait MyTrait<R> {}

impl dyn MyTrait<&str> {
    fn exactly(to: &str) -> impl MyTrait<&str> {
        MyStruct(to)
    }
}
```

Comment: And what if I want foo to work with anything, not only &str?

Comment: @caeus The same: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=983ab7518f79f3f1239d4051eafc062e